# asp.net dropdown decimal values wrong rounding

Tags: c#, asp.net, math, double, decimal

I am having weird error when I am trying to get a value from dropdown. All the values are decimal, such as 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, etc
When I am converting to decimal I am getting 1, 5, 7, when I am converting to double, I Am getting 1.0, 5.0, 7.0. 
What is the proper way to get the values in decimal or double as 0.1 or 0.5 for example?
Thanks, Laziale

example:

```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAgentPercEdit" runat="server">
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="">Select Percentage</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.01">0.01</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.05">0.05</asp:ListItem>        
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.1">0.1</asp:ListItem>  
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.3">0.3</asp:ListItem>                                    
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.5">0.5</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.6">0.6</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.7">0.7</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.75">0.75</asp:ListItem>                                                                  
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.8">0.8</asp:ListItem>                                 
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.9">0.9</asp:ListItem>                                 
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.95">0.95</asp:ListItem>
                                 <asp:ListItem Value="0.99">0.99</asp:ListItem>
                             </asp:DropDownList>

 util.Update(Convert.ToInt32(hfLifee), Convert.ToDecimal(ddlAgentPercEdit.SelectedValue), Convert.ToDouble(ddlAgentPercEdit.SelectedValue));
```

I am getting for 0.9 for example values: 9, 9.0.
I also tried toSingle, I am getting 9.0
Thanks

Comment: If you give an example of how you are converting it then we can see where you are going wrong

Comment: How are you converting the values ? does your culture consider `.` as the decimal point ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a localization issue. Try to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
decimal d = decimal.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Many cultures use the point as thousand- instead of as decimal separator.

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/1k4SEZ)